# A java program that can terminate another java program

Tags: java

I have written a java program that can read the epc code of rfid card when the card is shown to the sensor.
Now, I need a different program that can terminate the program which is reading the card.
In my program I have written a function that can stop reading the card, but I don't know how to use that function in other program to terminate the currently running program

Comment: What is the question? Can you provide your code please?

Comment: You would need to find a way for the two programs to communicate with each other. But maybe you should rethink your whole design, why are there 2 programs in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty open-ended and not really Java-specific. There are a lot of kinds of [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), take your pick.

A few options off the top:

- Store the PID of the first process in a file when you start it, and then the second process can stop it by sending a kill signal. This is a lightweight option because it doesn't involve modifying the first process, but has the disadvantage of being platform-specific and not being able to cross a machine boundary.
- Have the first process act as some kind of socket-based server and the second process access it as a client. This is nice because it works over the network, you can take advantage of the existing procotol if you end up needing to expand the scope of the IPC (e.g. to add authentication, additional functions beyond just termination, etc.), and you can leverage existing clients (e.g. if you use HTTP, maybe you just use curl instead of building something in Java for the second process).
- Use a message-passing platform like Akka, or some RPC library. If you want to keep your mind inside the JVM and learn as little as possible about anything else, you might take one of these approaches, but you'd end up coupling the two processing together to an extent that doesn't sound necessary.